# Windows 7 - Duplicate two displays with a different refresh rate output

Tags: windows, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, refresh-rate

Thanks for taking the time to look at my question!

To start, my hardware, and what I am attempting to do:
I have a NVIDIA GTX 780 as my graphics card (and I love it!) stock speed and BIOS configuration. I recently got an Elgato HD60 capture card. I am currently attempting to set up a system where any output from my Asus VG248QE monitor is duplicated on another graphics card output and sent to the capture card (as a monitor) to be, well captured, and output onto my laptop. (In the title I had mentioned two displays due to that my computer is recognizing the capture card as a display--the capture card also has an available passthrough, primarily why I think it is registered as a monitor.)

The problem:
I have my VG248QE connected through a display port, and I really want it to be outputting its full, 144hz refresh rate, as gaming at anything less than 120 really lacks in excitement. At the same time, the capture card has a max capture of 60hz, and due to the fact it is connected through HDMI, I am aware that that is the maximum refresh rate I would get from that connection anyway.

When I go to set up the monitor and capture card in this way, even after a careful configuration, as soon as I begin to duplicate the displays, my 144hz monitor is locked to 60hz. Even more so, not only locked as a max, but a minimum too!

What I have tried:
I have tried quite a lot of different tests, but one of the most prominent occurrences I have come across is that I have even tried manually overriding the monitor's output refresh rate in its configuration with the help of a couple utilities, and that much worked, except that, (rounding here) each frame it would output would only update every two frames (effectively 60hz again)

Additionally, from a lot of the searching I had done online to try and discover a solution, it seems that the issue is coming from the fact that the capture card is registered as an HD TV display (and I do not know if this is because of the HDMI connection, or the hardware itself) and when the computer recognizes a connection to an "HD TV" it locks all GPU outputs to 60hz. Again, I am not certain if this is the cause, but it seems pretty suspicious to me. Upon testing again while writing this, when I switch over to duplicate mode, my monitor is also then registered as an HD TV, and therefore locking it to the maximum of 60hz...

Also note that the separate refresh rate problem is **not** present while in extended mode, only when duplicating did all of the things I previously mentioned begin to happen.

In final, I am asking if anyone knows of some method, program, or both where I could trick the card that this is also a PC monitor, or maybe override this lock so that I can output different resolutions on duplicated displays? Thanks again!

Comment: I wonder if it is a drm (HDCP) issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a total of roughly three weeks, I finally came to a solution.

I started by going into NVIDIA control panel, and making a custom resolution for my Elgato. I set this resolution at 144hz just like my monitor. Of course I am not trying to get 144hz out of the card, but I want the computer to 'think' that I do (additionally, sense I am using HDMI, it is going to be physically limited to 60hz anyway.)

After doing that, I went back to set up the duplicate displays mode like I had done many times before. After doing so, I saw a feature I missed: "Change source." After changing the source of the capture, it then locked out all the configurations on the Elgato, but enabled them on my monitor, allowing me to set it to the desired 144hz.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with CRU, resolution software, make 1920x1080 resolution at 144 Hz for my Philips TV, even though it doesn't support it, restarted my PC, duplicated screen, and now I have 144 Hz on my monitor, while duplicating screen to my 60 Hz Philips TV.